# Can't both add a JAR to my Java project in Eclipse and have it seen in Git

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, apache-poi

I am new to Java and all. I have a project and there is an external JAR file (Apache POI) which I want to add to it. So I created a directory called `vendor` and put the file there and went to Eclipse and added the file to the build path and within Eclipse everything looks fine but when I checkout the git repo Git does not seem to know about the new directory and file. What is going on?

Also, I want to make sure that when a friend downloads and opens the project she will **not** have to configure the build path all over again so there must be some configuration thing to be done but I have no idea. So I'd like a help with that, too :)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is my .gitiginore content:

```
*.class

# Library development interface for
# testing methods et cetera.
src/ui

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# IntelliJ specific files/directories
out
.idea
*.ipr
*.iws
*.iml
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

.DS_Store

# Eclipse specific files/directories
.metadata
bin/

# NetBeans specific files/directories
.nbattrs
```

Comment: you shouldn't be putting binary dependencies in Git, you should be using a dependency management system like Maven, or something similar.

Comment: Ok, so your .gitignore file is masking out JAR files, which is why your JAR does not show up when doing a `git status`. You can either choose to start tracking JARs by removing that line (bad bad!), or you can start using a dependency management tool, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `vendor` directory is not relative to your project folder (which is what I presume Git is managing) then Git will never be aware it exists. You would need to create the folder somewhere underneath the root directory that Git is managing.

As far as sharing your workspace configuration with colleagues, its entirely possible to check in the `.project` and `.classpath` files for the project into Git.

A much more viable alternative to all this manual fudging though, would be to simply use a dependency management tool like Maven. With it the only thing you would need to check into version control is the POM file. The dependencies would then get automatically setup for your colleague when she checked out the project (assuming she is using a recent version of Eclipse with m2e installed).

Comment: yes, it is within the git repo folder. really weird thing happening here.

Comment: just checked here, Eclipse might doing something to my .gitignore somehow. When I remove it everything appears to Git but the file has no mention of the new directory whatsoever.

Comment: Is it? What does `git status` report for the folder in question. Do you see untracked folders?

Comment: the new stuff do not show up. I solved it by just temporarily removing the .gitignore file, adding the new content and bringing back the .gitginore

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Add your .gitignore to the question please.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, you have ignored all JAR-files in your .gitignore (*.jar). If you want only add this specific jar and continue ignoring other jar files, you can forcibly add that jar with the command

```
git add -f vendor.jar
```

and commit that. Otherwise remove that entry from gitignore and add and commit.